# Loopback: How to include a relationship results in a query

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have two models: NewsItem and user. Each NewsItem belongs to a user.

```
"relations": {
"user": {
  "type": "belongsTo",
  "model": "user",
  "foreignKey": "publisherId"
}
}
```

The relationship is been saved in database, so that is working.

I'm having trouble to list all the NewsItem with the name of the user associated.

```
 app.models.NewsItem.find({
    include: [
        {
        relation: 'user',
        scope: {
          fields: ['name']
        }
      }
      ]
  },  function(err, newsItems) { ...
```

According the docs (https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter) the NewsItem.user will **point to the relation method instead of the user instance**.

Does anyone know how I can access the user name value?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, I need to call **NewsItem.user()** to the get the object instance.